# Ajustar tamaño de una celda según su contenido en QTableWidget

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Actualmente estoy trabajando con el widget QTableWidget de la libreia PyQT5 y estoy agregando un widget dentro de cada una de las celdas, sin embargo me surgue el siguiente problema:

**Problema:**
El widget que ingresa a una celda no se muestra completo ya que la celda no logra ajustarce al tamaño del widget

**Posible solución:**
Trate de usar la propiedad `resizeRowsToContents` en la tabla pero no funciona y el resultado que obtengo es como este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa en la imagen la tabla no se ajusta al tamaño del widget que ahora esta en la celda 0,0

Solamente si agrego un tmaño predefinido a la tabla es como logra mostrarse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resultado Esperado:**
Sin embargo lo que deseo obtener es que el tamaño se ajuste en automatico en cuanto ingrese un nuevo elemento a la celda, por ejemplo:

- 1 elemento QPusButton con medidas 10x10 en la celda 0,0
- 1 Elemento QLabel con medidas 30,30 en la celda 1,0

y asi sucesivamente que la celda se ajuste a ese tamaño

**Código**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QTableWidget,QPushButton,QWidget,QVBoxLayout

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table.setRowCount(3)
        self.table.resize(400,300)
        
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton()
        btn.setText("Press Me")
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.table.setCellWidget(0,0,widget)

        self.table.resizeRowsToContents()

app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si te entendí bien, pero prueba esto:

> QHeaderView::[**setSectionResizeMode**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode)(QHeaderView::ResizeMode mode)
>
> Sets the constraints on how the header can be resized to those described by the given mode.

> enum QHeaderView::[**ResizeMode**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum)
>
> The resize mode specifies the behavior of the header sections. It can be set on the entire header view or on individual sections using setSectionResizeMode().

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QTableWidget,\
    QPushButton, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QHeaderView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()                                                   # +
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)                                        # +

        self.table = QTableWidget(3, 3, self)
#        self.table.resize(400, 300)

        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents) # +
        self.table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)   # +
        
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)                               # + 
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.table)                                           # +
        
        widget = QWidget()
        btn = QPushButton("x")                
        btn.setFixedSize(25, 25)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        self.table.setCellWidget(0, 0, widget)

        pixmap = QPixmap('lena.jpg').scaled(50, 50)  
        label = QLabel()
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.table.setCellWidget(1, 1, label)

        self.table.setCellWidget(2, 2, QLabel('Hello World'))

#        self.table.resizeRowsToContents()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Main()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]